# Python tkinter Treeview more columns than specified

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, ttk

I have the following code for a ttk Treeview:

```
listbox = ttk.Treeview(
    tab_player,
    columns=('Player', 'Rating', 'Price'),
    selectmode="extended",
)

listbox.heading('#0', text='Player', anchor=tk.CENTER)
listbox.heading('#1', text='Rating', anchor=tk.CENTER)
listbox.heading('#2', text='Price', anchor=tk.CENTER)
listbox.column('#0', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=80)
listbox.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=20)
listbox.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=30)

listbox.grid(row=5, column=5, rowspan=7, sticky=W)
```

My insert function is as follows:

```
def insertitem():
        GUI.listbox.insert('', 'end', values = (GUI.listbox_content.get(), 
                                                GUI.listboxr_content.get(), 
                                                GUI.listbox_content_price.get()))
```

When I launch my app, I have one additional column and the inserted data is not as I want (data in wrong columns).

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `"#0"` always refers to the *tree column*, not for data columns.  So use `"#1", "#2", "#3"` instead and set `show="headings"` to hide the *tree column*:

```py
listbox = ttk.Treeview(
    tab_player,
    columns=('Player', 'Rating', 'Price'),
    selectmode="extended",
    show="headings"  # hide the tree column
)

listbox.heading('#1', text='Player', anchor=tk.CENTER)
listbox.heading('#2', text='Rating', anchor=tk.CENTER)
listbox.heading('#3', text='Price', anchor=tk.CENTER)

listbox.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=80)
listbox.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=60)
listbox.column('#3', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=60)
```